# Holomorphic function with complex series

Tags: complex-analysis

We consider $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^{n!}$.

I want to show that is it is not possible to find  $ g \in H(\mathbb{D} \cup D(z, r))$, where  $z \in \partial\mathbb{D}$ and $r > 0$, such that  $\left. g \right|_{\mathbb{D}}= f.$

I mean by
 $H$:=holomorphic 
$\mathbb{D}$= the unit disc $\mathbb{D}(0,1)$

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Find a dense set of points on the unit circle where the series diverges.

Comment: @Chappers You need more than that. For example $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n$ extends to $\mathbb  C \setminus \{1\},$ even though this series diverges at every point of the unit circle.

Comment: @zhw. True. I suppose "tends to $\infty$" would be a better criterion.